# Inline style code on new large project Angular2

Tags: angular

Sorry for my english. I'm starting a new project, with around 300+ components, and I'm thinking of using inline styling (CSS, HTML, and script in the same file).

Is it a good idea to be able to read more easily a number of components like that?

Thank you very much for your comments and suggestions

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. While this question might attract opinionated answers, the approach you want to take is not ideal. When you want to (style)lint your code, or make simple adjustments, it's not easy to do this within one file where you have multiple sources (CSS, HTML, JS).

Answer (score 1):

For so many components, it is a better practice to keep your css in their own files and your scripts in their own files.

Look at https://github.com/angular/components

For an example of how the angular developers have separated different parts of functionality into their location.  This concept, called "Separation of Concerns", helps to make a system easier to write, learn and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a one folder or file to store styling. For example you can create a folder and create files for the features with regard to your application. So that you can manage everything in single place.
For example

```
  scss  <-- Styling store in this folder
    - components  <-- Different features in the application
    - modals
    - pages
    - navbar
```

Hope this answer helps